# Making an image act as a button in kivy

Tags: python, android, button, kivy, guid

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput 
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.image import Image


 class FirstPage(GridLayout, ButtonBehavior, Image):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs): 
            super(FirstPage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
            
            self.cols =2
            self.row_force_default = True
            self.row_default_height = 100
            
            self.add_widget(Label(text='Enter Name: '))
            self.name = TextInput(multiline=False) 
            self.add_widget(self.name)
            
            self.submit_name = Button(text = 'Submit name', font_size = 30)
            self.submit_name.bind(on_press = self.sub_name)
            self.add_widget(Label())
            self.add_widget(self.submit_name) 
        
        def sub_name(self, instance):
            if self.name.text == '':
                name_error = Label(text= 'Please put your name')
                self.add_widget(Label())
                self.add_widget(name_error)
            else:
    
                name = Label(text = 'Hello' + ' ' + self.name.text)
                self.add_widget(Label())
                self.add_widget(name)
            
            
            self.inside = FloatLayout()
            
            self.inside.cols = 1
            self.add_widget(self.inside)
            
            self.title = Label(text ='[b]Please choose your country[/b] '  + f'[b]{self.name.text} 
            [/b]',pos=(200,200), markup=True )
            self.inside.add_widget(self.title)
            self.pic = Image(source='unitedkingdom.png', on_press=self.ha)
            self.inside.add_widget(self.pic)
            
        def ha(self, instance):
            print('ha')
    
            
            
            
    class WeatherApp(App):
        def build(self):
            return FirstPage()
        
        
        
        
    if __name__ == '__main__':
         WeatherApp().run()
```

I want to make the image act as a button however when i run the app i get a random white box and my picture doesn't at as a button. Does this have to do with the way i added the button behaviour, any suggestions are appreciated. In addition could the answers please be in python code because i have some problems with my computer that does not allow me to use a kv file, thanks.

Comment: Don't inherit from multiple widget types, i.e. `GridLayout` and `Image` here. This may not be causing your issue though.

Comment: Also your code is quite convoluted - you don't even make use of the fact that your object inherits from `Image`, instead you add _another_ `Image` widget to it and set the source of that. Can you trim the example down to be truly minimal? Also check that the file `unitedkingdom.png` exists and is in the directory you are running your code from.

Comment: Also also, it's incredibly unlikely that "problems with your computer" don't allow you to use a kv file, more likely you've misunderstood how that works and can get it working easily enough if you want.

Comment: i created a separate class, however it still did not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
class united_k(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs): 
        super(united_k, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
        
        self.pic = Image(source='unitedkingdom.png', on_press=self.ha)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.pic)
        
    def ha(self, instance):
        print('ha')
```

i created this new class under the class above and it still did not work, if possible could you write out the code in order to help me understand